Probability of an event in sample space of an experiment that we wait for something particular to occur.
From chapter 2 of A First Course In Probability by Sheldon Ross:


A pair of dice is rolled until a sum of either 5 or 7 appears. Find the probability that a 5 occurs first.


Solution Manual says:
$$
P(E_n) = \left(\frac{26}{36}\right)^{n-1}\frac{6}{36}, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(E_n) = \frac{2}{5}
$$
$E_n$ is the event that neither a sum of 5 nor a sum of 7 occurs in the first $(n-1)$ trials and the sum 5 occurs in the $n$th trial.
Why do we divide by $36^n$? What actually is the sample space? Isn't it all of the possible outcomes of the expriment which actually has infinite outcomes ?
EDIT: My approach have been comprehensively explain in the comment below the final answer, Please check that out too.

The way I read this is that $P(E_n)$ is the probability that neither a sum of 5 nor a sum of 7 occurs during the first $n - 1$ trials but that a sum of 7 occurs in the $n$th trial.  The sum over all such outcomes is $3/5$, not $2/5$, so the probability that a sum of 5 is obtained before a sum of 7 is $1 - 3/5 = 2/5$.  Please check whether you have written the problem and its solution correctly.

I have added an explanation about your comment to the context of the question

Given your description of $E_n$, then $P(E_n) = \left(\frac{26}{36}\right)^{n - 1} \cdot \frac{4}{36}$ since there are only four outcomes that will produce a sum of 5 when two fair six-sided dice are rolled.  With that change, the sum over all possible trials is indeed $2/5$.

(This treats a more general scenario than the OP.)
Consider an experiment with (potentially) infinitely many repeated trials. Let the single-trial sample space be a finite set $S$ with equally-likely elements, so the experiment's sample space is the Cartesian product $\Omega=S\times S\times S\times \cdots$
Our basic assumption is that trials are mutually independent; i.e., the probability measure on the subsets of $\Omega$ is the product measure defined by
$$\begin{align}P(A_1\times A_2\times A_3\times\cdots)&=P_1(A_1)\cdot P_2(A_2)\cdot P_3(A_3)\cdots \\
\end{align}$$
with single-trial probabilities $P_i(A_i):=|A_i|/|S|=P_1(A_i)$ for any $A_i\subseteq S$.
Now suppose $A$ and $B\subseteq A$ are subsets of $S$, and consider the event
$$E=\bigcup_{n=1,2,3,...} E_n$$
where $$E_n= \underbrace{\bar A\times\bar A\times\cdots\times\bar A}_{n-1}\times B\times S\times S\times\cdots$$
and the bar denotes complement. Thus $E_n$ is the event in which $B$ occurs on the $n$th trial, and $A$ does not occur before that trial.
Theorem: If $B\subseteq A\subseteq S$ with nonempty $A$, then $P(E)={|B|/|A|}$.
Proof:
$$\begin{align}P(E)&=P\left(\bigcup_{n=1,2,3,...} E_n\right)\\[1ex]
&=\sum_{n=1,2,3,...}P(E_n)\\[1ex]
&=\sum_{n=1,2,3,...}P_1(\bar A)^{n-1}\cdot P_1(B)\\[1ex]
&={1\over 1-P_1(\bar A)}\cdot P_1(B)\\[1ex]
&={P_1(B)\over P_1(A)}\\[1ex]
&={|B|/|S|\over |A|/|S|}\\[1ex]
&={|B|\over |A|}\\[1ex]
\end{align}$$
IOW, all trials before the final one --the only one in which $A$ occurs-- are irrelevant to whether $B\subseteq A$ occurs in the experiment, reducing the experiment's sample space to the equally-likely outcomes in $A$ alone. (Note that $P(E)=P_1(B)/P_1(A)=:P_1(B\mid A)$, the single-trial conditional probability of $B$ given $A$.)
For the OP we have
$$\begin{align}
S&=\{(x,y): x,y\in\{1,2,...,6\}\},\quad|S|=36\\
A&=\{(x,y)\in S: x+y\in\{5,7\}\},\quad|A|=10\\
B&=\{(x,y)\in S: x+y=5\},\quad|B|=4\\
\end{align}$$
so $P(E)=2/5.$

Aside:
Interestingly, Exercise 12 of Chapter 1 in Introduction to Probability Models, also by Ross, is

Let $E$ and $F$ be mutually exclusive events in the sample space of an experiment. Suppose that the experiment is repeated until either event $E$ or event $F$ occurs. What does the sample space of this new super experiment look like? Show that the
probability that event $E$ occurs before event $F$ is $P(E)/ [P(E) + P(F)].$

This explicitly asks for a description of the (necessarily infinite) "super" sample space, but none of the several "Solution Manuals" that I've found online for this exercise even bother to mention it.
Of course this "super experiment = repeated experiments" is just my "experiment = repeated trials": the "super" sample space can be taken as just our $\Omega=S\times S\times\cdots$. With $E,F$ subsets of $S$, and $A=E\cup F$ and $B=E\subseteq A$, we again have the event of interest
$$\bigcup_{n=1,2,3,...}\underbrace{\bar A\times\bar A\times\cdots\times\bar A}_{n-1}\times B\times S\times S\times\cdots 
$$
so the above theorem applies to give the probability as
$${P(B)\over P(A)}={P(E)\over P(E\cup F)}={P(E)\over P(E)+P(F)}$$
since $EF=\emptyset$.

I think your sample space only contains the elements from infinitely many experiments; for example It doesn't contain something like (2, 5) or (3, 7). @r.e.s.

And also, Why you simply say $P_i(A_i):=|A_i|/|S|=P_1(A_i)$?

@VacationDue20000 Every such event is uniquely represented; e.g. "(5,3) on the 2nd roll" is represented by the set $S\times{(5,3)}\times S\times S\cdots\subseteq\Omega$, where $S$ is the "single-trial sample space" that occurs on every single trial. These are assumed to be "independent repetitions" of the same kind of trial every time, so each is modeled by the same "single-trial probability measure"; i.e., $P_i=P_1$ for all $i$. The trials are supposed to be "fair", so the elements of $S$ are equally-likely, implying $P_1(A)=|A|/|S|$ for any $A\subseteq S,$ including $P_1(S)=1.$

@VacationDue20000 This way of using an infinite set to represent a finite set is somewhat analogous to using an infinite-length decimal to represent a terminating decimal; e.g., $0.123000...=0.123.$ (But unlike decimal representations, these set representations are unique!) BTW, if your example (3,7) meant "sum is 3 on 1st roll and sum is 7 on 2nd roll", then this would be represented by the set ${(\omega_1,\omega_2,...)\in\Omega: \text{sum}(\omega_1)=3,\text{sum}(\omega_2)=7}\subset\Omega$, where $\text{sum}(\omega_i)$ is the sum of the pair of dice outcomes in $\omega_i$.

My intention was to somehow calculate the probability by first calculate the size of the universal sample space which is obviously infinite and each time divide the size of the event by that thing, Which it seems not to be a good approach because the outcomes in the sample space are not equally likely, So I'm really sorry for the time and I got here.

Actually, the points in $\Omega=S\times S\times\cdots$ are equally likely -- but they all have probability $0$. Note that $\Omega$ is the set of all infinite sequences $(s_1,s_2,\ldots)$ with $s_i\in S$, so there's a 1-1 correspondence with the set of base-$|S|$ numerals of real numbers in the interval $[0,1].$ In fact this correspondence produces a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, in the sense that for any interval $I\subseteq[0,1]$, $P(I)$ is the length of $I$. (There can be no uniform distribution on a countable infinite set, but $[0,1]$ and $\Omega$ are uncountable.)

Your solution manual overcomplicates this. I do not have the text but I imagine there is an implied solution process given the section it's in.
The event happens or it does not at each "roll". Once one of the given events has occurred you stop. There are 4 ways for them to sum to 5, and 6 ways for them to sum to 7.
So the answer is $4/10=2/5$.
For your question about $36^n$, the author of the solution is stating that in the $n^{th}$ roll of two dice there are $36^n$ elements in the sample space.

Shouldn't the sample space be something static? The sample space that you are describing is changing and growing over time.

@VacationDue20000 The occurrence of the event "5-occurs-before-7" is determined entirely by the final roll and is unrelated to any "neither-5-nor-7" rolls that may precede it. So the sample space can be reduced to just the 10 equally-likely outcomes that have a sum of 5 or 7 in the final roll, there being 4 of these with a sum of 5, giving 4/10=2/5 as the answer. It seems to me that the other answers so far proposed rely upon concepts the book hasn't yet covered -- specifically conditional probability, independence, and/or random variables.

@r.e.s. your argument is incorrect I think (although it leads to the correct answer). Because you are not caring about the prior rolls being nor 5 neither 7.

@VacationDue20000 I've posted an answer that proves it is correct (assuming independent trials).

Think of it as an infinitely repeated Bernoulli experiment (you can, and perhaps should, model this entire problem with a geometric distribution and derive all results rigorously). $E_n$ is the event that the first $n-1$ attempts yielded a sum that was neither equal to 5 nor 7 and that the sum of the $n$-th throw is 5. $10$ out of $36$ possibilities yield a sum of either 5 or 7, while $4$ out of them sum up to $5$. Thus, we have $\mathbb{P}(E_n) = (\frac{26}{36})^{n-1} \cdot \frac{4}{36}$. The event that the sum of $5$ occurs before the sum of $7$ is the union over all $E_n$, i.e. the probability is the sum over all $\mathbb{P}(E_n)$, which is $\frac{4}{10} = \frac{2}{5}$ using the geometric series.
EDIT: Since you're asking for an exact model, I will try to provide one using the geometric distribution. I think the issue here is that you're thinking of the $36^n$ coming from the cardinality of the state space, but this is not exactly true.
In our experiment, we roll two dices until the sum is either 5 or 7. Let $X$ denote the random variable that tells us how many tries it has taken us until we've gotten one of the desired sums. This could potentially take us any number of tries. Thus, our state space is $\mathbb{N}$. Thinking of only one throw, the probability of getting a sum of either 5 or 7 is $\frac{10}{36}$. Thus, the probability of $n-1$ failures and a success on the $n$-th try is $\mathbb{P}(X = n) = (\frac{26}{36})^{n-1} \cdot \frac{10}{36}$. The $36^n$ is derived from the independency of each experiment and the underlying probabilities of the Bernoulli experiment (we have $p = \frac{10}{36}$ and $(1-p) = \frac{26}{36}$).

Maybe i haven't had stated my confusing so right. Please read this new edit.

@VacationDue20000 I will write a new comment where I'll give a more rigorous model and explanation.

Is there a way that you could explain this without use of random variables and distributions? the book has introduced the problem in the chapter that it has just introduced the axioms of probability so there is no definition of random variables and distributions.

To be straight can you even draw a Ven Diagram for your argument?
